# SOAP XML request for initializing an Object value in JAVA Class

Tags: java, soap, soapui, soap-client

I am having the below JAVA Class :

```
@WebService()
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.DOCUMENT, use = Use.LITERAL, parameterStyle = ParameterStyle.BARE)
public class Demo extends JaxWsWebService
{
@WebMethod(operationName = "createMethod")
@WebResult(targetNamespace = "xyz.com/")
@RequestWrapper(localName = "Testing", targetNamespace = "xyz.com/", className = "com.Test")
public void createMethod(Testing testingData) throws SOAPException {

    System.out.println(" createMethod service --- xId = " + testingData.getXId() "); // xId is coming as NULL
    System.out.println(" createMethod service --- name = " + testingData.getName() "); // name is coming as NULL
}
}
```

Now I am calling the above JAVA method using my SOAP XML Request which is below :

```
<x:Envelope xmlns:x="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:NS1="xyz.com/">
<x:Header/>
<x:Body>
<NS1:createMethod>
<NS1:Testing>
    <xId>12345</xId>
    <name>abcd</name>
</NS1:Testing>
</NS1:createMethod>
</x:Body>
</x:Envelope>
```

Now, when I am calling the SOAP request using the SOAP client, the call is successful and is going inside the JAVA method but the main issue is the "testingData" instance of "Testing" class is not getting initialized.

Due to this, I am getting the value of 'xId' and 'name' variable as NULL in my JAVA method. Any suggestions on this would be helpful it looks like I am making mistake in my SOAP request calling but unable to figure it out.

Please suggest. TIA

Comment: Did SoapUI generate that XML request for you? I'm somewhat puzzled, that you've got annotations declaring the operation, but inside your XML, it's just used as datatype. Looking at your Java code, I wouldn't expect the <NS1:createMethod> should be there at all. I may be mistaken.

Comment: Steen : createMethod has to be used else its not getting inside the JAVA method. I am having some more params inside Testing bean, do I need to declare all of them in my SOAP request ?

Comment: I would start out by importing the generated WSDL directly from the webservice itself. Once SoapUI has the WSDL, it can generate an XML request for you, that complies with what the webservice expects you to send to it.

Comment: @Steen : I am having the wsdl file and have imported it. After that I am sending this particular request in which the parameter class "Testing" object "testingData" is not getting initialized

Comment: And it validates according to the schema? Then I don't think I can help you. It must be a serverside problem. Sorry.

Comment: className = "com.Test" ... Is that an actual class?

Comment: Yes. Test is class in which getters and setters have been defined

Comment: But you pass another parameter of type Testing that makes me think THAT is the class with the getters and setters: public void createMethod(Testing testingData)

Comment: Yes. That the name for reference

Comment: "Testing" != "Test". Shouldn't it say createMethod(Test testingData)

Comment: Looks like I made a type while writing in stack overflow. Its com.Testing only. Not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the place where I was going wrong :

```
<x:Envelope xmlns:x="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:NS1="xyz.com/">
<x:Header/>
<x:Body>
<NS1:createMethod>
    <xId>12345</xId>
    <name>abcd</name>
</NS1:createMethod>
</x:Body>
</x:Envelope>
```

In the XML request , I removed the `<NS1:Testing>` starting and ending `</NS1:Testing>` tags and finally it started working for me.